# How to access json data and use in if condition in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Following is my AJAX function code:

```
$('#request_form').submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    var formdata = false;

    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
    }

    var formAction = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        url         : 'xyz.php',
        type        : 'POST',    
        cache       : false,
        data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success: function(response) { 
            //Here I'm facing issue in checking whether the $response[error_message] is empty or not
            if (!response.error_message)
                alert(response.error_message); 
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here in response following is the content coming from PHP. This content is already converted into json format using the method `json_encode()`

```
{
    "error_message": "Id can't be blank<br>Please select Date<br>Image can't be blank<br>"
}
```

I want to check whether the array response[error_message] and if it's not empty then I want to show the content in alert box otherwise do nothing.

Please help me in this regard.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your condition appears to be backwards - try removing the `!`

Comment: maybe `if ( response.error_message != undefined && response.error_message != null && response.error_message != "" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
$('#request_form').submit(function(e) {
    //This should be the first line
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var formdata = false;

    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
    }

    var formAction = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        url         : 'xyz.php',
        type        : 'POST',    
        cache       : false,
        data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success: function(response) { 

            var responseObject = $.parseJSON(response);

            //Here I'm facing issue in checking whether the $response[error_message] is empty or not
            if (responseObject.length != undefined && responseObject.length > 0)
                alert(responseObject.error_message); 
        }
    });

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I think you are asking me to use response and not data on line $.parseJSON(data)?

Comment: Yes, sorry i edited my answer. Also added the extra check `responseObject.length != undefined` for if you didn't define `error_message`. Also changed `alert(response.error_message);` to `alert(responseObject.error_message);`

Comment: It's going in if now but not able to print the alert.

Comment: Did you changed `alert(response.error_message);` to `alert(responseObject.error_message);`?

Comment: Yes I used alert(responseObject.error_message); but still not able to print alert.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't empty? Or does the alert box shows empty? Also show how you create your json array in PHP.

Comment: I'm sure It's not empty since I'm getting it in console of firebug. The empty alert box is also not coming.

Comment: So what's your output in firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
if ( response.hasOwnProperty('error_message') &&  '' != response.error_message ){
  alert(response.error_message) ;
}
```